# How can I generate all non-isomorphic not-only-simple connected graphs with some restrictions?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, multigraphs

As the title says, I'd like to generate all non-isomorphic connected undirected graphs with specified numbers of vertices and edges. Also, I'd like to make the restriction to the degree of all vertices in the graph as $3 \le d(v_i) \le 4$.

**Notice:** I have no restriction for simple graph, so multi-edges and self-loops should be included, too!

It seems that the simple case could be generated by the program named nauty. I have no idea that if it works for generated all graphs or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with nAUTy, or more exactly with a pair of tools in the suite : `geng` and `multig`. For example, the following `geng` command:

`geng -c 4 > simple.g6`

gives all connected simple graphs on 4 vertices. This can then be passed to `multig` like:

`multig -u -D4 simple.g6`

I'm using the `-u` flag here to just count them and the -`D` flag to restrict the maximum degree to 4. If you remove the `-u` flag, and write to a file, you can then use `showg` to convert the `g6` format graphs into a more readable format.

There does not seem to be a minimum degree option, so you might have to use `pickg` to do this. With all these tools, there should be instructions in the manual, or use the `-help` flag.

Comment: Do all non-simple graphs are generated in this way?

Comment: @FenyutanchanWu - Apologies, but I do not understand. Are you asking if this will give you all non-simple graphs?